# Preconfigurar un navegador web

Tags: java, c#

¿Es posible preconfigurar un navegador web (Firefox, Internet Explorar, Chrome) con la configuración que yo necesitara? Algo así como generar un .exe de firefox con el navegador ya preparado?

O quizás editar los archivos donde estos navegadores guarden la configuración.

Aclaración:

Me refiero, por ejemplo a que si Firefox establece la fuente por predeterminado a 16 en la instalación , a que lo haga a 18. Si deshabilita los pop-ups, por defecto, hacer que no lo haga. Todos estos parámetros que se configuran en about:config yo pueda configurarlos automáticamente de alguna manera. Buscaba orientación principalmente. ¿Hay algún archivo donde se guarde toda esta configuración que yo pueda editar?. –

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En lugar de una pregunta tan genérica como esta, tal vez la deberías [edit] y explicar un poco mas en profundidad que es exactamente lo que quieres conseguir, por ejemplo, que configuraciones te interesa modificar.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  No es una pregunta sobre programacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si es exactamente lo que buscas pero en `about:profiles`, tienes la opción de acceder al administrador de perfiles de Firefox. En un perfil de firefox se almacenan datos como marcadores, historial, extensiones y configuración. Tienes más información [en este enlace](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/usar-el-administrador-de-perfiles-para-crear-y-eli).

Estos perfiles tienen una ruta, que por defecto es:

> %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

Aquí puedes encontrar distintas carpetas (una para cada perfil) con nombres del tipo `********.default`. Si copias esta carpeta y la pegas en otro PC podrás llevarte toda la configuración contigo. [En este enlace tienes más información sobre todo el proceso.](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/hacer-una-copia-de-seguridad-y-restaurar-tu-inform)

Otra opción sería llevar el programa en versión portable en una memoria USB, de modo que al utilizarlo en otro PC siempre lleves contigo tu configuración.
Espero que te sirva, no es exactamente en la instalación pero creo que se consigue lo que buscas.

Comment: Exacto, esta era la orientación que quería. Muchas gracias.